# reCAPTCHA callbacks using data attributes

Tags: javascript, callback, recaptcha

According to reCAPTCHA 2.0 [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param), we can define the callbacks of success and expired through data attributes - here is my code:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="window.iid.recapchaFilled" data-expired-callback="window.iid.recapchaExpired" data-sitekey="<?php echo $conf['recaptcha']['key']; ?>"></div>
```

The JS functions are:

```
window.iid['captcha'] = false;
window.iid['recapchaFilled'] = function(){
    window.iid.captcha = true;
    console.log(window.iid.captcha);
};
window.iid['recapchaExpired'] = function(){
    window.iid.captcha = false;
    console.log(window.iid.captcha);
};
```

For some reason after checking the reCAPTCHA nothing is fired ( calling them manually works fine ) - I know I can use the `render` method and assign the callbacks but I wonder what is wrong with the data attributes way. Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `data-callback="iid.recapchaFilled"` instead? Or, better still, have you tried `data-callback="recapchaFilled"` where `recapchaFilled` function is global?

Comment: @PeterKA yes I have, still not working.

Comment: I am using the data attributes with global functions for callbacks and everything works fine.